# suggestions for mobile framework for Iphone?

Tags: iphone, android, ios

I've created 2 android apps allready and I can find my way through it easily because I know some java ... now I need to port my app to iphone....

but I don't want to write xcode... I've downloaded titanium mobile but haven't had time to test it out also. I need to install osx to download the apple sdk...

coming from android what framework would I adapt to best?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult if you don't write in XCode or use Objective C. Your other option is to write it using HTML and Javascript which could limit the interactivity of the app (but not always).  You might want to look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) for such development type.

The HTML + JS + PhoneGap approach should work for typical app as PhoneGap allows you to access typical function such as camera, storage, gps or accelometer. The only thing that might diminish its function if your app is high on touch interactivity. While this paritcular issue is will get better in time, today the native code is still performing much better than the Javascript counterpart.

Comment: will phonegap allow me to make send notifications to the user when the app is not running?

Comment: Not that I know of (I might be wrong). In general, unlike Android, there are very few things you could do in background for iOS

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of your application.
Titanium mobile is a good framework but you'll not be able to make heavy applications or games. You may find good framework on this another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android).

However, if Lua does not scare you can check for the [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) framework from Ansca mobile. In my opinion, this is the best compromise between Android / iPhone cross-platform and the performance. However it's not free (349$/year), but you can test during one month for free.

Comment: thanks for the link to the topic